# Undefined index: 0 when using hook_node_insert() Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm writing a custom module to insert data into database using `hook_node_insert()` when creating a new node. But if I left any field in the node empty without adding anything (non required field) and save the field I get the following error even though i have used isset function to check for empty fields.

```
Notice: Undefined index: 0 in add_customer_node_insert() in line no:5
```

Line no -5

```
$node_id = isset($node->field_id['und'])? $node->field_id['und']['0']['value']:NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only check if `$node->field_id['und']` is set but not if the next part of the multi dimensinal array `$node->field_id['und'][0]` is set which you use for your assignment to `$node_id`. Change your statement to

```
 isset($node->field_id['und']['0']['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your following code

```
$node_id = isset($node->field_id['und'])? $node->field_id['und']['0']['value'] : NULL;
```

`$node->field_id['und']` is an array. You should check this by using `empty()` function for example like this

```
$node_id = !empty($node->field_id['und']) ? $node->field_id['und']['0']['value'] : NULL;
```

**OR if you want to use `isset()` function**

```
$node_id = isset($node->field_id['und']['0']['value']) ? $node->field_id['und']['0']['value'] : NULL;
```